# Regular expression in Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I want to extract a word from a string and then use that word in my regex.

My string looks like this:

```
 val s = "null_eci_count"
```

I want to derive the below string from the above string:

```
sum(cast((eci is null or eci in ('', '0', 'null', 'NULL')) as int))
```

I used replaceAll and had derived a part of the above expression:

```
scala> s.replaceAll("null_", "sum(cast((").replaceAll("_count"," is null) as int))")
res69: String = sum(cast((eci is null) as int))
```

Please suggest a way to derive the whole expression.

Comment: What is the logic? I tried to do something but I do not understand what the logic is.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
val eci = s.split("_").drop(1).head
val result = s match {s"sum(cast(($eci is null or $eci in ('', '0', 'null', 'NULL')) as int))"
```

Comment: I am not sure how to incorporate this logic in the below statement I am currently using: val tgt=spark.sql("select * from ctx_monitor.xpo_click_counts");  val col=tgt.columns.slice(4,tgt.columns.length).mkString(",").replaceAll("distinct_","count(distinct ").replaceAll("_cnt",")").replaceAll("null_", "sum(cast((").replaceAll("_count"," in (null,'')) as int))")

Comment: I have no idea what that statement is doing. Perhaps you should ask your question differently ...

Answer (score 0):

Select the middle part of the string as a group (i.e. eci) `.*?_(.*?)_.*` and then return `eci` with the group reference `\1`.

Answer (score -1):

I used ArrayBuffer to do this:

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
val tgt=spark.sql("select * from ctx_monitor.xpo_click_counts")
val a = tgt.columns.slice(4,tgt.columns.length)
for (e <- a) {
if (e contains "null"){ val c=e.replaceFirst("null_",""); 
col += "sum(cast((" + c + " is null or " + c + " in('','0','null','NULL')) as int))"}}

val cols=col.mkString(",")
```